# Using Pager to rotate through Page Fragments

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm using Google Appmaker to produce an internal dashboard.  The dash requires that a series of page fragments (designed as 'cards') be cycled through using a pager.

I'm a little unsure on how to do this - my thinking is that I'd need to set up a data source for the pager as an array of the page fragments I want to display, but I could be thinking about that all wrong.

I need to be able to reliably use page fragments as reusable UI elements and display them on the page in a way that can be 'thumbed' through using the pager controls.

Would I need to do this in a single fragment? Looking for guidance here.

Comment: Not sure, why you need a datasource, for cycling through. Can't you just use a simple integer 'pageNumber' and depending on what page number it is you change the pageFragment to the one that needs to be displayed. I have not tried playing with pageFragments dynamically so not sure if they can be changed at runtime.